# extracting top values from df.describe and then placing in graph

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Sorry I'm new to Python so apologies if this seems to really simple but I'm stumped. I've got a csv files and I've used df.describe() to get the following output:

[image]

My question how would I go about getting the top and freq values and then display them in a pie chart? I thought perhaps it would be something like df.describe(top) or df.describe[top] but both of these returned errors and I haven't been able to find anything online that deals with this. Any guidance would be much appreciated

Okay so now I'm able to get the values thanks to the answer provided but how could I use them in a pie chart?

I tried to do the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Top answers': [df.describe().loc['top']],
                   'Frequency': [df.describe().loc['freq']]},
                  index=['Most Common answer', 'Frequency'])
plot = df.plot.pie(y=df.describe().loc['freq'], figsize=(5, 5))
```

This however gives me the error:

"None of [Int64Index([2, 2], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"

Not sure how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

`df.describe().loc['count']`
and
`df.describe().loc['unique']`

Comment: thank you but would you be able to look at my edited question to help with the pie chart?